# Remove AdUnit from Placement with DFP API

Tags: ruby, google-dfp

I am using the ruby gem to interface with DFP (DoubleClick for Publishers) version 201108.  I am able to add an AdUnit to a Placement using the `AdUnitAction.Type -> AssignAdUnitsToPlacement` but have not been able to find a way to remove an AdUnit from a Placement.  I can use the DFP web interface to do this manually but I am looking for a way to programmatically do it.  I've looked through the [API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/dfp/docs/start.html) but I didn't find anything that looked like what I needed to do.

How can I remove an AdUnit from a Placement using the API?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID of the placement, you can always remove it in the Placement object itself:

http://code.google.com/apis/dfp/docs/reference/v201108/PlacementService.Placement.html

Just fetch the placement, modify the targetedAdUnitIds and then update it.

For future reference, the DFP API Forum: [https://groups.google.com/group/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api](http://code.google.com/apis/dfp/docs/reference/v201108/PlacementService.Placement.html) is a great place to ask these questions as we monitor it a bit more.